# Using redis with Passportjs for sessions does not work

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, redis, passport.js

I am using Nodejs with ExpressJS. My application is deployed on heroku where I have the "redistogo" add-on installed for my app.

I am making use of PassportJS to help with the authentications and sessions.

I want to use redis to store the sessions after a user logs in so that if the application restarts, the logged in user does not lose his session.

This is my code (stripped to bare minimum for brevity):

```
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

app.configure('development', function () {
    var redisUrl = url.parse(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL),
        redisAuth = redisUrl.auth.split(':');

    app.set('redisHost', redisUrl.hostname);
    app.set('redisPort', redisUrl.port);
    app.set('redisDb', redisAuth[0]);
    app.set('redisPass', redisAuth[1]);
});

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'My secret key',
        store: new RedisStore({
            host: app.get('redisHost'),
            port: app.get('redisPort'),
            db: app.get('redisDb'),
            pass: app.get('redisPass')
        })
    }));
    //Passport configuration
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

});
```

I use `request.isAuthenticated()` on requests to verify if the user is logged in.

If the user logs in, based on console statements, I see that the login is a success. PassportJS correctly logs the user in. However, `request.isAuthenticated()` returns false.

If I remove the redis code and keep only the PassportJS code, then it works perfectly.
What more should I do to work with redis and PassortJS?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the option for your cookie to set it either to false or ture , but the recommended is true

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'My secret key',

    // add this line
    cookie : {secure : true},


    store: new RedisStore({
        host: app.get('redisHost'),
        port: app.get('redisPort'),
        db: app.get('redisDb'),
        pass: app.get('redisPass')
    })
}));
```